# Making complex method interruptable in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I've got pretty complex method, with few loops and other method calls. I'd like to make it possible to interrupt this method. The only solution I've found to do so, is by checking if `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. The problem is I'd like to check it in every iteration of every loop and in few other places. After doing that the code does not really look so nice.

So there are two questions really.
 1. Is there any other way to stop the method when thread was interrupted than checking the same flag over and over again?
 2. Is it better - mostly in case of performance - to just add `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` condition in every loop or use some method like the one below?

```
void checkIfInterrupted() {
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        throw new InterruptedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to check that thread which is running is interrupted?

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz I want to check if it was interrupted by some other thread. Let's consider it as task which could be interrupted by user.

Comment: I think your exception example is the preferred way to manage this. There is the deprecated, Thread#stop, but it is deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated and dangerous, I should add.

Comment: Are you looking for [Thread.yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--)?

Comment: @mabi: no, the OP is not looking for `Thread.yield()`.

Comment: @mabi, it has nothing to do with interruption. It is just a way to suggest scheduling, mostly useless because modern OS do scheduling very well even without it.

Comment: @Holger yeah, I didn't see the "stop thread" thing. Then again, why would I do a complex computation only to lose it half-way through?

Comment: @mabi, suppose because the user clicked the "Cancel" button, to name just one good reason.

Comment: See Chapter 7 of *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

Answer (score 4):

Preferred way is to check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() every loop in your thread. Viz. Java Concurrency In Practice - Listening 7.5:

```
class PrimeProducer extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;

    PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
        } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
        /* Allow thread to exit */
        }
    }

    public void cancel() { interrupt(); }
    }
```

> There are two points in each loop iteration where interruption may be
>   detected: in the blocking put call, and by explicitly polling the
>   interrupted status in the loop header. The explicit test is not
>   strictly necessary here because of the blocking put call, but it makes
>   PrimeProducer more responsive to interruption because it checks for
>   interruption before starting the lengthy task of searching for a
>   prime, rather than after. When calls to interruptible blocking methods
>   are not frequent enough to deliver the desired responsiveness,
>   explicitly testing the interrupted status can help.